# R - kNN - an error occurred - NA / NaN / Inf value in invocation of foreign function (argument 6)

Tags: r, knn

Im new in ML and Im trying to apply some of the methods on data. Unfortunately, I have a problem with "KNN". That error occurs:

> Warning: NA values appeared due to transformation Warning: NA values appeared due to transformation Error in command 'knn (train = train.Sz, test = test.Sz, cl = train.Sz_l, k = 202)': NA / NaN / Inf value in invocation of foreign function (argument 6)

Below is my code:

```
data <- read.csv('~/Desktop/test1.csv', sep = ";")

data1 <- subset(data,select=c(4,5,6,7,8,12,15,16))
dat.d <- sample(1:nrow(data1), size = nrow(data1)*0.7, replace = FALSE)
train.Sz <- data1[dat.d, ]
test.Sz <- data1[-dat.d, ]

library(class)

train.Sz_l <- data1[dat.d,5]
test.Sz_l  <- data1[-dat.d,5]

NROW(train.Sz_l)

knn <- knn(train = train.Sz , test = test.Sz, cl = train.Sz_l, k = 202)
```

and some reproducible data:

```
dput(head(data1,15))
structure(list(Miesiąc = c("styczeń", "luty", "styczeń", "styczeń", 
"styczeń", "styczeń", "styczeń", "styczeń", "styczeń", "styczeń", 
"styczeń", "styczeń", "styczeń", "styczeń", "styczeń"), 
    Kwartał = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Terminal = c("Katowice", "Legnica", "Katowice", 
    "Legnica", "Sosnowiec", "Wrocław", "Legnica", "Katowice", 
    "Katowice", "Legnica", "Gliwice", "Wrocław", "Wrocław", 
    "Legnica", "Wrocław"), Towar = c("RTV", "RTV", "Telefony", 
    "AGD", "Komputery", "AGD małe", "AGD do zabudowy", "Telefony", 
    "RTV", "AGD małe", "AGD", "RTV", "Komputery", "AGD małe", 
    "RTV"), Status.szkody = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Kraj = c("PL", "PL", "PL", "PL", 
    "PL", "PL", "PL", "PL", "PL", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "PL", 
    "PL"), Usługa = c("Express", "Express", "Express", "Express", 
    "Express", "Express", "Express", "Express", "Express", "Express", 
    "Express", "Express", "Express", "Express", "Express"), Partner = c("Partner D", 
    "Partner A", "Partner D", "Partner A", "Partner C", "Partner D", 
    "Partner D", "Partner A", "Partner D", "Partner B", "Partner C", 
    "Partner A", "Partner C", "Partner B", "Partner D")), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I do not know how to deal with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at your sample data, it is apparent that you have character values for several columns. Nearest neighbor assumes you are working with numeric data.

Comment: So what is the best solution to solve this?

Comment: Use only numeric data. In the data you provided that would be Kwartał and Status.szkody. None of the others are numeric. You could post your question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) to get suggestions on clustering categorical data.

Comment: You could dummy code the categorical columns into several numeric binary columns, then perform the kNN.